# How can I utilize window's "open with" option in order to load file data into a python file?

Tags: python, windows

I am creating a text editor in python. If I had a .txt file and I wanted to load that information into a python script and store it as a variable, how could I obtain that file path via windows “open with” drop down? Basically, how can I utilize the “open with” feature in windows for  python?

Comment: It's not clear what you actually want. Do you want to make it so your script shows up in the "open with" dialog, and selecting your script there causes your script to run and operate on the selected file?

Comment: All that does is pass a cli argument of the file path to the executable